# C# - Marking Pixels on an Image

Tags: c#, image-processing, matrix

I have a Matrix [y][x] with x= arround 5000 and y= arround 13 values in it.
And i need to mark them in different colours (depending on the value) on an Image.

My Problem: The Image is much bigger than the Matrix. If i Colour 1 Pixel for 1 Value i only get 1/3 in X and only like 1/20 in y painted. But i need to Paint the whole Image with the amount of Values i have.

Solution i tried: Marking multiple Pixels at once with each Value
Problem: I can not scale X and Y at the same time -> way to complicated for me :/

Solution i can think about: Scaling the Image to the exact Size of the Matrix, then painting the pixels (1 pixel = 1 value) and after that resize the Drawn Image to a Size that it is visible.

It would be great if you could help me here, maybe you have an even better solution for this Problem, than i can think off... Note: I am a newby on C#.

My current try: (marking 5 pixels with each value of the matrix)

```
Bitmap image1;  
            image1 = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Downloads\test.bmp", true);  


            Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(image1.Width, image1.Height);  
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
            {
                graphics.DrawImage(image1, 0, 0);
            }



            Color pixelColor = newImage.GetPixel(0, 0); //set pixel color to white
            int x, y;   //loop for matrix
            double akt_Wert = 0;

            int x1=0, y1=0; //loop for picture
            for (x = 0; x < max_Col; x++)      /
            {

                for (y = max_Rows - 1; y >= 0; y--)   
                {

                    try
                    {

                        akt_Wert = Convert.ToDouble(rows[y][x]);    //tries to convert the current Value to double, if it fails its NaN -> catch


                        if (akt_Wert < 0.7) //if < threshold
                        {
                            for (x1 = x * 5; x1 < x*5+5; x1++)
                            {
                                Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(pixelColor.R, 50, 50);
                                newImage.SetPixel(x1, y1, newColor);
                            }

                        }

                        if (akt_Wert >= 0.7) //if >= threshold
                        {
                            for (x1 = x * 5; x1 < x*5+5; x1++)
                            {
                                Color newColor = Color.FromArgb(pixelColor.B, 10, 0);
                                newImage.SetPixel(x, y, newColor);
                            }

                        }

                    }

                    catch   //value is NaN
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show("Spalte = NaN");

                    }


                }


            pictureBox1.Image = newImage;       // Set the PictureBox to display the image.               
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5); //needed to avoid error

        }

                   }
```

Thanks in advance!
Regards
Christian

Comment: _I can not scale X and Y at the same time -> way to complicated for me_ ????? Huh?? If you can scale x what would be different doing the same with y??? You just need to work with floats, both to determine the SizeF for FillRectanlge and the coordinates..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example.

Note the use of `floats` to avoid data loss by integer division.

Also note that I create a semi-transparent brush color so we can see the original image shine through..

[image]

```
Bitmap b = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(fileName);

// the data array sizes:
int numX = 3000;
int numY = 30;
int[,] data = new int[numX, numY];

// create test data:
Random rnd = new Random(8);
for (int i = 0; i < data.GetLength(0); i++)
     for (int j = 0; j < data.GetLength(1); j++)
          data[i, j] = rnd.Next(123456);

// scale the tile size:
float sx =  1f * b.Width / data.GetLength(0);
float sy =  1f * b.Height / data.GetLength(1);

// now fill the tile-pixels
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
{
    for (int x = 0; x < data.GetLength(0); x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < data.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            RectangleF r = new RectangleF(x * sx, y* sy, sx, sy);
            Color c = Color.FromArgb(99, Color.FromArgb(data[x, y]));
            using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(c))
                g.FillRectangle(brush, r);
        }
    // display or save or whatever..
    pictureBox1.Image = b;
}
```

If you actually want to create a new Image you can use `g.Clear(someColor)` to set its backcolor. And, of course you would create it not from a file but from scratch: `Bitmap b = new Bitmap(1234,1234);`; maybe include a special `PixelFormat` setting here.

Comment: Thank you for your quick Answer! I really appreciate it!
But i have a question, i do not understand the code fully:

1. you store the array size in data[numX, numY] 
2. you create a test data with "i counting to numX" and "j to numY" 
3.  data[i, j] = rnd.Next(123456);   what does this do?
4. scale the tile size -> this is the new size of "a Pixel" (1 Array Value = 1 Tile right?)
5. you fill the tile picutres in random clours right?

I tested it with my image, but the Problem is the image Size is now much bigger than it was before, and i only see a part of the image.

Thanks again

Comment: 1,2&4: Yes. 3&5: yes, this creates a (seeded) random generator for (repeatable) random colors. - The resulting size of the bitmap should not change at all as I'm only drawing onto the area it already has. To make the PictureBox show all the image make sure to set its SizeMode to Zoom (or maybe Stretch)!

Comment: Ahh i got it! Thank you soo much! really really helped me! i wish you a great day! THANKS

Comment: Btw: You can also place the PBox in a Panel with autoScrolling and set the SizeMode of the PBox to Autosize. Then the image will be shown in its original size.

Comment: Ah okay, i did that now! Thanks again, i posted an Answer under this, maybe you could give me another help there. Really hard stuck atm. Thanks in advance